# Filling Out Column with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

What is the correct way to create a workflow in SPD that will take the data from a "Contract Expiry" column, subtract 'x' amount of days from that date, and display the new date in a column?

This is likely a very simple request, however I'm unable to figure out the correct way to create the workflow on SharePoint Designer (new to SPD).

I'm working on creating email notifications when a contract in a document library is close to expiry.
The obvious choice to me was a calculated column, however it seems IMP doesn't recognise this.

Please let me know if I should elaborate/ explain this a little better.
I'm still rather new to SharePoint and am struggling to find more specific documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the WF you need:
- First define a variable with type date and set the value of your column "Contract Expiry"
- since it is not possible if the value is empty, check if it is greater than 01.01.1970
- The use "Add Time To Date" modifying the just created variable
- Set the new obtained value to the second field (you need a second column/field to store this value)

Otherwise you could use the "Wait til data" option, and then simply send your email.